# CISO goes to jail if something goes wrong?

Tags: legal, risk-management

I'm building up most functions out of opensource projects; honeypots, firewall, ERP, CRM, PBX, physical security, software security, network security, security government, asset policy management, etc.

I'm doing as much as I can in order to minimize risks but in the worst scenario, let's suppose my company gets compromised by any vector; some employee got phished, 0-day scenario. There's incident response, documentation, and procedures to resolve the issue and mitigate it.

I wish to know if I'm running a risk if I sign as a CISO in a company. I have my plans but I'm kind of new to this corporate world.

I've heard that people hire services and if something happens you can blame the service, for example. I really dislike the idea of spending money on a service I can implement on my own, but maybe I need this to cover my own liability?

Comment: This is a purely legal question, i.e. off-topic here and on-topic on [law.se]. Please note also that laws differ between countries so your currently provided information might not be sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: This discussion might help you: [Defense in Depth: When Are CISOs Responsible for Breaches?](https://cisoseries.com/defense-in-depth-when-are-cisos-responsible-for-breaches/)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: if you leave out the "goes to jail" part, the role and the responsibilities of a CISO does fall into strategic infosec. However, this remains partly opinion-based, as they aren't standardized, but varies between companies.

Comment: *"I really dislike the idea of spending money in a service I can implement on my own ..."* - don't underestimate the time, manpower and knowledge needed to build such a service on your own, to keep it always up to date and to monitor it. Don't overestimate the knowledge you have as a single person compared to the knowledge aggregated in companies which specialize in such services. On the other hand don't believe all the exaggerated and simplified marketing claims either.

Comment: You overlooked the fact that any security policy must be approved by the stockholder, that can save you from jail, but you remain the first to be liable for any incident.

Comment: Asking random strangers about your corporate and legal liabilities for 1. this company and its policies, and 2. your country is not the way to go. If you are new to the corporate world, then you need to talk to a lawyer in your area to advise you.

Comment: What I've learned so far is that if you are in charge of anything, your will always be responsible for something. However, you won't pay damages unless there's been *gross negligence*. Also, in some fields that are considered especially complex (like most IT, INFOSEC included), it is hard to prove gross negligence. If programmers had to pay damages, no one would want to be a programmer anymore. If possible though, you should consider getting some kind of insurance anyway.